# Looking for SFX- Islamabad Airport Ambience

Tags: sfx

Hi There,

I'm working on a drama-doc and need to find recordings from Islamabad Airport for it.

I was wondering whether anyone has any sort of recording from there?

Any help would be hugely appreciated .

Many thanks

Comment: If you want it to be authentic, the official language in Pakistan is English, and most television programming is also in English.

Comment: Do you need it super urgently? cause I live in Dubai and airports are always crowded with mostly Indians and Pakistanis, my cousin lives near a mosque I could get some records for you when they have their prayers,

Comment: It wasn't urgent Stephen.However,thanks a lot for a very kind offer. In the end I went with urdu adr and speakerphone ! 


Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounddogs.com

Look up Pakistan Walla, Urdu Walla, etc.

You don't have to have a recording that was done inside the airport.

A quick google search shows that it's got parallel floor/ceiling with tile floors and long wide open floors which means a bit of a long decay on anything happening.

Get an airport ambience (like what you hear in any airport, lots of verb of people walking and rolling luggage, tonal hums of large air conditioners, etc. and sprinkle in some ADR callouts you find on Sounddogs.

Then, get some specific lines and futz them to sound like they are being announced over a P.A.

It's pretty simple.

Comment: Thanks! That is how i did it in the end. Speakerphone pluggin worked a treat.

Answer (score 0):

Well my two cents is this:  Middle Eastern Music, puttering jeeps, rickety sounding cars, sand, islamic V.O. and loop group/walla